# Finding the optimal strategy for a Payoff matrix of 3x3 that can't be reduced

Tags: matrices, game-theory

I have the following Payoff matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix} 3&-5&0\\
    2&6&4\\
    2&5&6
\end{pmatrix}$$

I am trying to find an optimal strategy for both the row and the column players, but the method I familiar with only apply for 2x2 matrices. This specific matrix can't be reduced since there are no dominate rows or columns as far as I can see.

How to solve this payoff matrix and find the optimal strategies for the row and column players as well as the value of the game for this matrix ?

Note: One player is seeking to maximize and one to minimize, it's presented so -5 for example is the profit for the column player while it's the loss for the row player. Positive numbers are the profit of the row player. It's a zero sum game.

This following answer doesn't address my question since my matrix is not antisymmetric and have different criteria as far as I can tell : [Finding the optimal mixed strategy of a 3x3 matrix game.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477659/finding-the-optimal-mixed-strategy-of-a-3x3-matrix-game)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the optimal mixed strategy of a 3x3 matrix game.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3477659/finding-the-optimal-mixed-strategy-of-a-3x3-matrix-game)

Comment: No, my matrix is not antisymmetric and have different criteria as far as I can tell.

Comment: Abstract duplicate.

Comment: What do you mean ? The minimal criteria are different, there is a complication that isn't addressed there at all, I already said that..

Comment: What's the relationship between the goals of the row and column players?  Do both want to maximize payoff, minimize it, or is one seeking to maximize and one minimize?

Comment: one seeking to maximize and one minimize, it's presented so -5 for example is the profit for the column player while it's the loss for the row player. Positive numbers are the profit of the row player. It's a zero sum game.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you solve it by assigning variable probabilities to each of the first two rows and columns, calculating the expected payoff in terms of those variables, and then taking advantage of the fact that the first partial derivative of any of those variables must be $0$ (as otherwise one player would be able to improve his payoff by changing his probabilities) to get a linear system of four equations and four variables?

Comment: I would appreciate an example or a walkthrough

Comment: @RT.: Your expected value is $3p_1q_1+2p_2q_1+2(1-p_1-p_2)q_1-5p_1q_2+6p_2q_2+5(1-p_1-p_2)q_2+4p_2(1-q_1-q_2)+6(1-p_1-p_2)(1-q_1-q_2)$.  This gives the system of equations $3q_1-2q_1-5q_2-5q_2-6(1-q_1-q_2)=0$,$2q_1-2q_1+6q_2-5q_2+4(1-q_1-q_2)-6(1-q_1-q_2)=0$, $3p_1+2p_2+2(1-p_1-p_2)-4p_2-6(1-p_1-p_2)=0$,$-5p_1+6p_2+5(1-p_1-p_2)-4p_2-6(1-p_1-p_2)=0$

Comment: I didn't understand why it's equal to zero. In any case running it through wolfram alpha it found that p1=10/29 and p2=23/29 which gives us in total 33/29 >1, and it doesn't seem right: https://tinyurl.com/32tjczbn. From what I understand zero sum games always have optimal strategy

Comment: 1) It's equal to zero because you are looking for minimum/maximum of payoff

Comment: 2) In the case where one or more of your probabilities is negative, it means that you aren't actually achieving the extreme value of the payoff.  Just set any negative values at 0 and fiddle with the others to find the actual extreme

Comment: It is not negative, the total of p1+p2 is bigger than 1

Comment: @RT.: Which means that the probability of the third row, $1-p_1-p_2$ is negative

Comment: Do you have a final solution for the optimal payoff in this case ?